# Cannot hide Panel in Grdivew - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to hide a Panel in Gridview but I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Protected Sub gvTally_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvTally.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Incomplete" Then
        Dim Panelhide As Panel = CType(e.Row.FindControl("Panel1"), Panel)
        Panelhide.Visible = False

    Else
        Dim Panelhide As Panel = CType(e.Row.FindControl("Panel1"), Panel)
        Panelhide.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is my Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTally" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True"
                                AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="gvTally_RowDataBound" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Small">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company">
                                        <ItemStyle Width="180px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Submitted" HeaderText="Submitted" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Variance" HeaderText="Variance" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Accepted" HeaderText="Accepted" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-small" Text="Unaccept" CommandName="Unaccept" Visible="False" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-small hidden-phone" Text="Accept" CommandName="Accept" />
                                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                                                <a href="#accSettings3" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-small hidden-phone" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="">Accept
                        </a>

                                                <div id="accSettings3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                            ×

                                                        </button>
                                                        <h4 id="myModalLabel3">Accept Validation
                            </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            Are you sure you want to accept the tally with the variance off?

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnacceptchanges" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
                                                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                            No

                                                        </button>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:Panel>

                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-small" Text="View" CommandName="View" />
                                            </td>
                    </tr>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

I am not sure why I cannot hide this Panel that contains other HTML and another Button Control even when I use FindControl.

I have other FindControls that work perfectly fine, but this one gives me the error that it cannot find the Panel1.

I am using the panel just to hide the code inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with the panel.

Make sure you have a data row and not a header or something.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

   ...

End If
```